# Install4J is stuck at Evaluation Key Expired dialogue has no options and user cannot advance past message

Tags: java, macos, installation, install4j

I am attempting to add a new key for the evaluation but the Swing Dialogue does not provide any radio buttons next to the text. I am using Mac OS 12.3.1 . I've attempted to use the command line, but get the same pop-up dialogue message. Has anyone had the same problem. Is there a work around?

[image: install4j key expired message with no options]

This is likely a Mac OS vs Java version issue. Install4j does not have any issues on my older Mac using 10.13.

There are no error messages printed in the output. Any advice on how to work around this issue?

edit: Solution --

The early release of install4j-v9.0.8 resolved the problem.

I was able to print the output from the CLI using a previous post. I added the following:

```
     /appDir$ INSTALL4J_LOG=yes install4j.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

Comment: Another detial. This error does not occur on windows. It is only on MacOS Monterey Version 12.3.1

Comment: I have the exact same error on MacOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: @PavelSpicak I was able to resolve the problem with an early release version of install4j v9.0.8

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from support:

To work around this issue, you can execute

rm "$HOME/Library/Application Support/install4j/v9/config.xml"

to start fresh.